# Вставка данных в таблицу происходит некорректно

Tags: c#, sqlite

Нужна помощь с одним вопросом. Когда я вставляю данные в БД почему то все значения меняются на названия самих столбцов, кроме столбца Format. Прикладываю код действия.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                string path_all = path + "\\1.db";
                SQLiteConnection DB = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format(@"Data Source={0};", path_all));
                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
                DB.Open();
                string query = @"INSERT INTO Billboards(Format, Size, Adress, Side, Price) VALUES (@Format, 'Size', 'Adress', 'Side', 'Price')";
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.Connection = DB;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Format", textBox1.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Size", textBox2.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Ardess", textBox3.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Side", textBox4.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Price", textBox5.Text));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                DB.Close();
```

Comment: Ну так ты и вставляешь литералы (да ещё как специально - обрамлённые одинарными кавычками), а не значения параметров...

Comment: Проблема в одинарных кавычках? Просто без них VS выдавал исключение формата SQL logic error or missing table no such column: Size и так далее по списку столбцов.

Comment: Написание параметров должно точно совпадать в тексте запроса и в операторе присоединения -включая и собакевича... но как-то предполагалось, что уж такую фигню Вы и сами способны поправить... у `@Format`-то как-то справились же ж.

Comment: Что я делаю не так? Скинул в описание вопроса доп. скришнот.

Comment: `string query = @"INSERT INTO Billboards(Format, Size, Adress, Side, Price) VALUES (@Format, @Size, @Adress, @Side, @Price)";`

Comment: Ну и проверьте всё остальное. ПОБУКВЕННО. Опечатки - ЕСТЬ!

Comment: Какого...Я заменил свою строчку вашей и получил вот это: Исключение не обработано System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: "unknown error
Insufficient parameters supplied to the command". Это еще что за?

Comment: А нет ли в передаваемых значениях, к примеру, кавычек?

Comment: И проверили ли, как сказано выше, все тексты ПО БУКВАМ? а то в запросе имя параметра `@Adress`, а в привязке `@Ardess`...

Comment: Мой косяк, я действительно должен был проверить этот Adress. Спасибо большое за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Выдернул вам такой пример вставки новой записи. Надеюсь, сами найдете свои ошибки.

```
private async Task<int> SaveItem(RssItem item)
{
    int result = 0;
    try
    {
        using (var connection = GetConnection())
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO items (id, title, description, date, link)" +
                " VALUES (@id, @title, @description, @date, @link)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", item.Id);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("title", item.Title);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("description", item.Description);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", item.Date);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("link", item.Link);

            await connection.OpenAsync();
            result = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Ошибка в {nameof(SaveItem)}: {ex.Message}");
    }

    return result; }
```